# Dynamodb update multiple Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Suppose this is my DB table

```
[
{PK:'#author_1', SK: 'author', name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#author_2', SK: 'author', name: 'ryan'},
{PK:'#book_1', SK: '#author_1', title: 'hello 123', author_name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#book_2', SK: '#author_1', title: 'hello 456', author_name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#book_3', SK: '#author_1', title: 'hello 789', author_name: 'aytor'},
 ]
```

My question is if the **admin change author** name how can I update all books author name.

Access pattern: get `author_pk` and update all books where Book `SK=author_PK`

I'm trying to solve this problem using `AWS-SDK` for node `js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating data is a fine way to model one-to-many relationships in DynamoDB.  However, it can be a less appealing strategy if the data you are duplicating is subject to change.  If it's an infrequent operation, like updating the author of a book, it may be an acceptable approach.

With this data model, you'll need to fetch all books by author and manually update the author name of each book.  You could either `scan` the table for all books by this author, or introduce a global secondary index on book items where the index PK = author_id and SK = book_id.  That way, you'd be able to `query` a list of books for each author and issue updates accordingly.

DynamoDB does not offer a batch update operation.  However, you can handle the concurrency in your application.  With the was node SDK, it would look something like (in pseudocode, I have not tested this)

```js
    const updates = [];
    let new_author_name = "Clancy"
    for (let i = 0; i < books.size; i++) {
        updates.push(ddb.update({
            TableName: 'MY_TABLE',
            Key: { PK: books[i].PK},
            UpdateExpression: 'SET #name = :name',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':name': new_author_name
            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                '#name': 'name'
            }
        }).promise());
    }

    await Promise.all(updates);
```

Comment: can you suggest me a model or approach for efficiently update book data for each time author data update. I'm using GSI to retrieve book data but I don't understand how can I update multiple book data at once when author changes.

Comment: I added an example of issuing multiple calls to updateItem using node (not tested).  Because AWS does not include a batch update API operation, you have to handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @seth-geoghegan gave is correct for the data you have. I wonder if you might want to change your data, however, to allow this to be a little easier. Instead of the `book` being the `PK` for book records why not make it the `author`? You may still need to add a GSI if you need to get to a book by it's ID, but it would be a `query` either way (currently you have the `book` as the `PK` and the `author` as the `SK`, meaning you can't get at a single book using a `get` without knowing the author too).

```
[
{PK:'#author_1', SK: 'author', name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#author_1', SK:'#book_1', title: 'hello 123', author_name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#author_1', SK:'#book_2', title: 'hello 456', author_name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#author_1', SK:'#book_3', title: 'hello 789', author_name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#author_2', SK: 'author', name: 'ryan'},
 ]
```

This would allow you to query all records for the author and update the author name.

If you still need to query for a book by it's ID just add a GSI for that.

```
[
{PK:'#author_1', SK: 'author', name: 'aytor'},
{PK:'#author_1', SK:'#book_1', title: 'hello 123', author_name: 'aytor', GSI1PK: '#book_1'},
{PK:'#author_1', SK:'#book_2', title: 'hello 456', author_name: 'aytor', GSI1PK: '#book_2'},
{PK:'#author_1', SK:'#book_3', title: 'hello 789', author_name: 'aytor', GSI1PK: '#book_3'},
{PK:'#author_2', SK: 'author', name: 'ryan'},
 ]
```

Comment: It's really helpful, now I'm able to retrieve books without author PK. But still, I don't understand how can I update duplicate data(author data in books) at once or efficiently when the author update.

Comment: There isn't an easy answer to that, which is why you generally want to limit duplicated data to immutable (or mostly immutable) data, or limit the number of times it is duplicated. When I do this I typically take advantage of DynamoDB streams; update the main record and in a stream handler lambda I'll locate the other records that need to be updated and update them in that code.